# Unity3d, Shooting at mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple arcade game however I am having trouble with shooting. The player will have this view.
[image]
I want the player to shoot at the mouse position, from the turret on the player character.

Here's my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gunController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 3f;
    public float fireRate = 3f;
    public float force = 10f;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject gunEnd;

    private GameObject bullet;
    private Camera mainCam;
    private float distance = 50f;
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    private bulletController bc;
    private bool canShoot = true;
    private Vector3 aim;

    void Start () {
        mainCam = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera> ();
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Get mouse position. You need to call this every frame not just in start
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);

        //declare your aim by adding +10f to the local.z position of your turret. Not 50f, because if your
        //car goes past 50f then it'll start shooting behind
        aim = new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, transform.localPosition.z+10f);
        //rotate turret to mouse
        //now make turret look at your aim not your mousePos - you want it to look at an X Y Z point, not X Y.
        gunEnd.transform.LookAt (aim);
        //get mouse click and asks if we can shoot yet
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)&&canShoot) {
            StartCoroutine(shoot());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator shoot(){
        //instantiates the bullet
        gunEnd.transform.LookAt (aim);
        bullet = Instantiate (bulletPrefab, gunEnd.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        bullet.transform.LookAt (aim);
        Rigidbody b = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        b.AddRelativeForce (Vector3.forward*force);
        canShoot = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (fireRate);
        canShoot = true;
    }
}
```

This only shoots backwards, behind the player in the same place regardless of position, or mouse position.

Thank you for reading and hope you can help! :)

Comment: Does your turret aim correctly (looks at the correct point in space) ?

Comment: may be in >>b.AddRelativeForce (Vector3.forward*force);<< value >>Vector3.forward<< do change to >>gunEnd.transform.forward<<?

Comment: The Turret does not aim correctly, however there is an empty gameobject under the turret which controls where the bullet spawns.

gunEnd.transform.forward doesn't work in place of Vector3.forward

Comment: Try using Raycast from your mouse position and aim to hit point.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from this line :

```
mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
```

Because the "Screen position" (Input.mousePosition) does not have any "depth" when you convert it to World space, I suspect the `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` to return a wrong value, even if you try to set the value of `aim.z` some lines after.

Try this instead :

```
    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos += Camera.main.transform.forward * 10f ; // Make sure to add some "depth" to the screen point 
    aim = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePos);
```

By the way, in the code above, `Camera.main` is used, but you should use the cached version you initialize in the Start function : `mainCam`

Comment: Got thrown an error, 'Assets/Scripts/gunController.cs(36,27): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Camera' does not contain a definition for `forward' and no extension method `forward' of type `UnityEngine.Camera' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?'

Comment: It shoots to the left, and slightly behind if the mouse is on the right of the screen. If the mouse is on the far left it will shoot almost straight

Comment: Well, it's hard to diagnose without more information. It seems to work fine here (Main camera : (0, 1, -3) ; Empty with the gunController ; Capsule as the GunEnd and a simple sphere as bullet prefab) . Are you sure you don't have colliders blocking the bullet ?

Comment: Hmmm, it almost works. I have the Vehicle, Childed under that is the turret with the gun controller script, also under the turret is an empty for the gun end. nothing collides with the bullet.